# determine HTML element position using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am parsing an HTML page using jsoup.  Is there a way to determine the position on the page of each element relative to the top of the page using jsoup?

Answer (score 1):

No, because Jsoup only parses HTML. You'll need something to take CSS & JavaScript into account -- depending on what you're doing, look into [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp), or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).